# Error graphing series of functions in MatLab

Tags: function, matlab

I want to graph a sequence of functions, the problem is best described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4776753/is-the-sequence-of-functions-uniformly-convergent-in-0-1) (see the coments of the question)

I plot the sequence of functions fn that should be included by the lines x+0.1 and x-0.1, but in the graph this is not possible; I attach the code

```
    n_max = 10;
x = linspace(0, 1, 1000);
fn_values = zeros(n_max, length(x));

for n = 1:n_max
    fn = zeros(size(x));
    for k = 0:(2^n - 1)
        Ik = [(k / 2^n), ((k + 1) / 2^n)];
        fn = fn + (k / 2^n) * (x >= Ik(1) & x < Ik(2));
    end
    fn_values(n, :) = fn;
end

figure;
hold on; 
for n = 1:n_max
    plot(x, fn_values(n, :), 'DisplayName', ['f_', num2str(n)]);
end

plot(x, x + 0.1, 'r', 'DisplayName', 'x + 0.1');
plot(x, x - 0.1, 'g', 'DisplayName', 'x - 0.1');

title('graph of f_n(x) and x + 0.1, x - 0.1');
xlabel('x');
ylabel('f_n(x)');
legend('show');
grid on;
hold off;
```

Whats wrong? any help is apreciated!

[image: graph]

Comment: What is your question here that is not already answered over at math SE?

Comment: @CrisLuengo That the code seems to be incorrect, since the graph of fn should be completely inside the region comprised by the lines x-0.1, x+0.1, which the code does not show.

Comment: I don’t know what theory you base yourself on for that assertion, but the people in that linked question seemed satisfied that the graph matches the equation. Let’s look for k=1, the lowest value. The equation says from 0 to 0.5 it has a value of 0, and from 0.5 to 1 a value of 0.5. This matches the graph, and is below the x - 0.1 line. I think your assertion is wrong. For a larger k, then yes, the function is between those two lines. The series converges to x, so for sufficiently large k, the series is within x-e and x+e. But only for sufficiently large k, not for any k.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It's true, but only for very large values of $k$ or $n$ too? thank you!

Comment: Yeah, I meant *n*, not *k*.